# How to append an index and values to an array dynamically with foreach PHP

Tags: php, symfony, web-deployment

I have this array and a value liken this...

```
'FirstBranch'

Array => (
     ['January'],
     ['February'],
     ['March']
)
```

And I need to create another array with the following structure...

```
['FirstBranch'] => array(
              ['January'] => array( 
                     'Value',
                     '%',
                     'Unit'
                    ),
              ['February'] => array(
                     'Value',
                     '%',
                     'Unit'
                    ),
              ['March'] => array(
                     'Value',
                     '%',
                     'Unit'
                    ),
             )
```

I tried to push the values through a foreach, but it doesn't work.
The code I did looked like this...

```
foreach( $months as $month ){
    $resultArray['FirstBranch'] = array( 
                   $month => array('Value',
                                   '%',
                                   'Unit' 
                                )
                            );
}
```

When i do this, throws an error and it just doesn't work... Any ideas?

Comment: Your array structure is weird, you have an array containing arrays of exactly one item. Why?

Comment: There, i changed it...

Comment: It's still the same...

Comment: It is not, the same, this array has more dimensions, and this is how i need it, it is not weird

Comment: `Array => (
     ['January'],
     ['February'],
     ['March']
)` this is the weird array of arrays. why not `Array => (
     'January',
     'February',
     'March'
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append your array using for each loop

```
<?php

 $array = array('January', 'February', 'March');

 $array2 = array('Value', '%', 'Unit');

 $newarray = array();
 foreach ($array as $key) {
   $newarray['FirstBranch'][$key] = $array2;
 }
 print_r($newarray);
```

> [Demo Here](https://3v4l.org/kQInE)

Comment: Thanks!  this is exactly what I need! I have no idea why I didn't think about this way to do it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the month names as keys associated with FirstBranch. Try:

```
foreach( $months as $month ){
    $resultArray['FirstBranch'][$month] = array( 
                   'Value',
                   '%',
                   'Unit'
                    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a built-in PHP function, [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php), that can simplify this.

```
$resultArray['FirstBranch'] = array_fill_keys($months, ['Value', '%', 'Unit']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<?

$months=array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun',...);

$FirstBranch=array();
foreach($months as $month ) { 
    $FirstBranch[$month]=array('Value', '%', 'Unit');

}
var_dump($FirstBranch);
?>
```

Which gives you:

```
   array(12) {
  ["Jan"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Value"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "%"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Unit"
  }
  ["Feb"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Value"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "%"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "Unit"
  }
```

And if you wanted to access the 3rd value in the Jan array:

```
echo $FirstBranch[Jan][2];
```

Which would print:
    Unit

Cheers,
-Joe